# Rspec current_path not showing the current_path but the previous one before the redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, rspec, integration-testing, capybara

I am visiting a page in my spec using capybara `visit` and then clicking another button which is redirecting it to another page. On the third line when I print the `current_path`, it still shows the old (first url) rather than the second one. I am using selenium-webdriver for chrome. Any idea on why it is happening?

Edit:

Selenium is opening another browser on line 2 and not redirecting. So, its showing the url of the previous browser and not the current newly opened browser.

`Rails 3.2.6`
`ruby 1.9.3`

In the definition of `current_path` and `current_url`, it says path and url of the current page. Does `current page` mean the last browser that was opened?

Comment: Did you switch to using the newly opened browser window?

Comment: I dont do anything. Selenium opens another browser on its own, after the command `click_button`.I was wondering is that the issue?

Comment: Yes, you have to explicitly switch to the new window. You probably want to do something like seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612038/with-capybara-how-do-i-switch-to-the-new-window-for-links-with-blank-targets).

Comment: That helped :) Thanks a ton. You can put your comment as the answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly switch to the new window.

To work with the new window, you can do:

```
new_window = page.driver.browser.window_handles.last 
page.within_window new_window do
  #actions performed in new window
end
```

Comment: Actually the following did the trick for me.`page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(page.driver.browser.window_handles.last)`