# Switching between the browser tabs using capybara web

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to automate an ecommerce website, wherein when I click on a particular link it creates multiple browser tabs and related pages will be displayed within the respected tabs.

Problem here is I want to switch between these browser tabs to automate the web pages within that tabs, but I don't know how to switch between browser tabs using Capybara.

I'm using Capybara with Ruby.

Comment: can you show your site's javascript / html which opens multiple tabs? from what i've gathered, capyara just uses the concept of windows, not tabs, and i'd be curious if it would work here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25093517/2981429

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Capybara, how do I switch to the new window for links with "\_blank" targets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612038/with-capybara-how-do-i-switch-to-the-new-window-for-links-with-blank-targets)

Answer (score -1):

From the [java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java) you need to send `Command` and `T` keys to open a new tab.